# What is the charge time of a capacitor C that is already at Vc volts, and I want to charge it to V volts? Vs = 5V the supply voltage

Tags: voltage, capacitor, capacitance, charging, time

In code, I've been using this formula:

charge time t = -ln(1 - Vc/Vs) * R * C

where R = 1.0 here so we can ignore it.  This is derived using Kirchoff's laws etc from a voltage source attached directly to a capacitor, where Vs = supply voltage = 5V is fixed (ideally), and C = 100F-100kF.  The production set up is 100kF, but I'm testing / debugging on 100F capacitors.

I'm having doubts about this formula though.  Previously I thought I needed Vc = the voltage I'm trying to achieve, but then where does the current capacitor voltage come into play?

Thanks for any guidance.  I know basic electronics and calculus, etc.  Not looking for t = 5*R*C or anything as I'd like something dynamic, and I'm not looking to model anything more than a voltage source attached to the capacitor directly.

So how can I tie in the current capacitor voltage, or alternatively what is the correct formula to use?  I've scoured the internet.

Thanks!

---

I'm thinking now that Vs should equal the voltage I'm trying to achieve?  But then the supply voltage is 5V, so I can't ignore that "higher voltaic pressure" or can I?

For my test setup the voltage I'm trying to achieve is 1V per capacitor, but in production it's 2.7V.

Comment: Why don't you use a simulator; they are extremely accurate on these things.

Comment: @Andyaka I have about 24 hours before we do a live test.  The code is pretty much perfect, except for this one formula.  What I mean is what the code is supposed to do it's doing, except I wish to increase the target voltage precision.  So with a bad charge time, the voltages might oscillate around the target voltage, I want to charge it and be done with it without having to discharge again.

Comment: According to the formula, the time is infinite, as the current becomes smaller and smaller when voltage goes closer to target, so it will never reach it. You have to define a limit, and most often t=5RC is used as the limit to say that cap has charged fully even if it just close enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation that you have for the time to charge to a voltage \$v_C(t)\$ is derived for an initial value of \$v_C(0)=0\$V.

For \$v_C(0)=V_0\$ the charge/discharge equation is $$v_C(t)=(V_0-V_S)e^{\frac{-t}{\tau}}+V_S$$ where, \$V_0\$ is the initial capacitor voltage, and \$V_S\$ is the supply voltage and the final capacitor voltage as \$t\rightarrow\infty\$.

Solving for \$t\$:$$t=-\tau\text{ln}\frac{V_S-v_C(t)}{V_S-V_0}$$

where \$v_C(t)\$ is the target capacitor voltage (final voltage) at time \$t\$. Of course \$\tau=RC\$

> R = 1.0 here so we can ignore it. This is derived using Kirchoff's laws etc from a voltage source attached directly to a capacitor

Be careful here, if a voltage source is connected directly to a capacitor, then \$R=0\$

Comment: Vf != Vs.  My Vs is 5V, while I only charge to Vf = 1.0V or 2.7V.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I have adjusted the answer to be more suitable.

Answer (score 2):

Write the equation for Vcap(t) starting from 0V, and solve for an artificial time tx when Vcap(t) would be Vc (as a function of Vc).

Then you can write an equation for capacitor voltage as a function of time using t+tx in the original equation, and solve for time.

It will be something of the form t' = -\$\tau [\ln(a) - \ln(b)]\$ where \$\tau = R \cdot C\$  which can be simplified to
-\$\tau \ln(a/b)\$

Comment: Thank you!  So I've got: tau = ln((Vs - Vc)/(Vs - Vt)) where Vc is cap start vtg and Vt = target vtg.  (Vs = supply).